# Why doesn't the class "mt-50" work in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried centering the h1 using mt-50, but it doesn't give me a margin between the red border and blue border. However, when I use CSS styling of margin-top:50px it gave me the desired outcome. Can anyone explain the difference, as I thought mt-50 in bootstrap is the same as margin-top:50px in CSS?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="header my-5 border border-danger">
  <h1 class="col-6 border border-primary mx-auto text-center mt-50"> Welcome to Food Mart </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: See the [spacing docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding). Centering is not done with margin anyway. You should be using [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#align-items).

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap doesn't provide a class `mt-50`. If you change to `mt-5` it will work.

[Bootstrap provides classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) from `mt-0` to `mt-5` plus `mt-auto`.

`mt-5` is set to `margin-top: 3rem`, if root font-size is 16px, mt-5 is 48px close to your 50px.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header my-5 border border-danger">
  <h1 class="col-6 border border-primary mx-auto text-center mt-5 d-block"> Welcome to Food Mart </h1>
</div>
```